# how to use only one exists clause for the below query instead of multiple exists clauses

Tags: sql-server

I have Orders , OrderSubscription and RentalOrder tables.
the relation between the tables is id(order)-->order_id(OrderSubscription). id(order)-->order_id(RentalOrder)

I want to find out those Orders where one of the OrderSubscription subs_status must be only one 'Active' status and can have other statuses as well and RentalOrder rental_status  should be 1 or more 'Purchase' .

So Based on the data, final result should be come as order id =1 and id=4 Records.

Written the below query and its working fine.Or Is there any other better way to filter the records like instead of two exist clauses ,can I make it one?

```
select *  from  Order As cc     
                WHERE 
                order_status='Active' and
                EXISTS (
                Select 'X' from OrderSubscription As cs 
                 WHERE 
                 cs.order_id = cc.id 
                 GROUP BY cs.order_id
                HAVING 
                        COUNT(CASE WHEN cs.subs_status in( 'Cancelled','Expired') THEN 1 END) >= 0
                  AND   COUNT(CASE WHEN cs.subs_status = 'Active' THEN 1 END) = 1
            ) 
                AND EXISTS
                            (
                                Select 'X' from RentalOrder as cr  WHERE
                                    crs.rental_status='Purchase' AND    cr.order_id=    cc.id                   
                             )

Create Table Orders(id number(5),order_number number(12),order_status varchar2(20));

insert into Orders Values (1,12345,'Active');
insert into Orders Values (2,5757575,'Active');
insert into Orders Values (3,979797979,'Active');
insert into Orders Values (4,3131313133,'Active');

Create Table OrderSubscription(id number(5),order_id number(5),subs_name varchar2(20),subs_status varchar2(20));

insert into OrderSubscription Values(1,1,'360 fhf','Pending');
insert into OrderSubscription Values (2,1,'720 cef','Active');
insert into OrderSubscription Values (3,1,'540 abc','Cancelled');


insert into OrderSubscription Values (1,2,'360 fhf','Pending');
insert into OrderSubscription Values (2,2,'720 cef','Pending');
insert into OrderSubscription Values (3,2,'540 abc','Pending');
insert into OrderSubscription Values (4,2,'adada abc','Active');


insert into OrderSubscription Values (1,3,'720 cef','Pending');
insert into OrderSubscription Values (2,3,'60 ert','Cancelled');
insert into OrderSubscription Values (3,3,'60 ert','Cancelled');

insert into OrderSubscription Values (1,4,'360 fhf','Pending');
insert into OrderSubscription Values (2,4,'560 fhf','Pending');
insert into OrderSubscription Values (3,4,'560 fhf','Active');


Create Table RentalOrder(id number(5),order_id number(5),order_number number(20),rental_status varchar2(20));

insert into RentalOrder Values(1,1,353535,'Active');
insert into RentalOrder Values (2,1,7575757,'Purchase');
insert into RentalOrder Values (3,1,868686,'Purchase');


insert into RentalOrder Values (1,2,1212,'Active');
insert into RentalOrder Values (2,2,58868,'Active');


insert into RentalOrder Values (1,3,57534,'Active');
insert into RentalOrder Values (2,3,86868,'Active');
insert into RentalOrder Values (3,3,3434,'Purchase');

insert into RentalOrder Values (1,4,86868,'Purchase');
insert into RentalOrder Values (2,4,7979797,'Purchase');
insert into RentalOrder Values (3,4,32323,'Active');
```

Answer (score 0):

The estimation plan for your data is the same (test it for a large data), but I think is more readable to write your query like this :

```
select cc.* from Orders cc 
where order_status='Active' and
cc.id in (select order_id from OrderSubscription group by order_id having COUNT(CASE WHEN subs_status = 'Active' THEN 1 END) = 1)
and 
cc.id in (select order_id from RentalOrder where rental_status='Purchase')
```